# Why do I get "functions that differ only by return type cant't be overloaded" error when nothing is really overloaded?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I have following example of c++ code in visual studio 2022:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

employee get_employee() {
    employee out = { 1, "John"};
    return out;
}

class employee {
public:
    int id;
    std::string name;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << get_employee().name;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, I get compiler complaining about `get_employee()`, specifically that *"functions that differ only by return type cant't be overloaded"*.

**But why does it do so, if I dont have another `get_employee()` definition anywhere in my code?**

I know that I can't create an instance of an class before I define the class itself, and moving `get_employee()` definition below `employee` class definition really solves the issue, but it doesn't explain why compiler says that *"functions that differ only by return type cant't be overloaded"* instead of saying that you *"cant crate an istance of a class before defining the class itself"*, and I would like to know why.

Comment: This code raises another error.

Comment: @273K really? What is the error you get?

Comment: The [mcve] does not compile with a different error message - live - https://godbolt.org/z/GWejvc9fd . Fixing the order does compile clean - live - https://godbolt.org/z/eecG5f8vG

Comment: @Richard Critten Thank you for your feedback, I will be more descripitive next time, but I am asking about Visual Studio specifically, not just any compiler.

Comment: The 4th pane in the live example(s) (above) is MSVC. In order left to right - source code, clang, gcc, MSVC.  The other compilers are there because they occasionally give different results or explain errors in a different way.

Comment: It raises 5 errors and neither of them is "functions that differ only by return type cant't be overloaded".

Comment: @Richard Critten Thats very wierd, but I really do get the error I get. You have any ideas on why? I use Visual Stuboid 2022 Community.

Comment: It sounds like IntelliSense (not the compiler) is getting confused. Fix the use before declaration problem (of `employee`) and re-compile.

Comment: @Richard Critten Ok, that makes sense, thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is fairly simple. You're trying to *use* `employee` before you've defined what it means. Move your definition of `employee` before the definition of `get_employee`.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class employee {
public:
    int id;
    std::string name;
};

employee get_employee() {
    employee out = { 1, "John"};
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << get_employee().name;
    return 0;
}
```

As to *why* the compiler gives a poor error message, my guess is that somehow or other the undefined name for the return type is tricking it into accepting the call to `get_employee` as it would have in old C, where a function without a declaration is presumed to return type `int`.

Then when it encounters the actual definition of `get_employee`, it has one entry already saying `get_employee` returns `int` and takes no arguments, and now sees what it's thinking is an attempt at overloading that also takes no arguments, but returns a `client` instead.

And that convinces it that what it's seeing is an attempt at overloading that uses the same parameter list (i.e., no parameters) but a different return type.